# Error Message with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am updating from ASP.NET MVC Identity 1 to 2 and I am using MVC 5. Everything worked fine when sending the email to finalise registering in Identity 1 but since updating I am getting this error message:

No IUserTokenProvider is registered.

From researching I think that I need to put this code into my application but I do not know where to put it?

```
var provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider("PaymentPortal");
                UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());
                userManager.UserTokenProvider = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
```

Comment: Where do you manage identity configurations? Do you have Custom UserManager Class which inherits from UserManager<ApplicationUser, string> ?

Comment: I have this in my accounts controller                       public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        
        public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {
        }

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
        }

        public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create CustomUserManager like below and register it owin startup, because then you have power to configure adentity configuration in one place.

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static CustomUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<CustomUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new CustomUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<YourDataContenxt>()));

            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = false;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            //manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;
            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug in here.

            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is: {0}"
            });

            // Two Factor Authentication

            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, string>
            {
                Subject = "SecurityCode",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });

            // Your Email service

            //manager.EmailService = new IdentityEmailMessageService(new EmailService(new MailServer()));
            //manager.SmsService = new SmsService();

            // Data Protection Provider

            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("Asp.NEt Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }
}
```

Then configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request Startup.Auth file.

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request

            app.CreatePerOwinContext(YourDataContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomUserManager>(CustomUserManager.Create);


            // Other relevant configurations 
        }
    }
```

In the controller you can get the instance as below.

```
private CustomUserManager customUserManager;
        public CustomUserManager CustomUserManager 
        {
            get
            {
                return customUserManager?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<CustomUserManager >();
            }
            private set
            {
                customUserManager= value;
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.